# Как на AlertDialog повесить OnItemLongClickListener?

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

Вызывается Dialog. Обработчик на нажатие повесил(onClick). Как повесить обработчик событий на LongClick и можно ли тут так сделать? Буду рад любой помощи или замечанию!

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new lertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
        builder.setTitle("Список: ")
               .setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        loadList((anyArrayList.get(which)));                            
                    }
                });                  

        return builder.create();
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Согласно [en-SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14163293/3212712) надо повесить слушатель показа диалога на экране. В этот момент можно достучаться до его внутреннего ListView и уже ему назначить слушатель:

```
final AlertDialog ad = builder.create(); //don't show dialog yet
ad.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() 
{       
    @Override
public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) 
{       
        ListView lv = ad.getListView(); //this is a ListView with your "buds" in it
        lv.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() 
    {
    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) 
    {
        Log.d("Long Click!","List Item #"+position+"was long clicked");
        return true;
    }           
    });     
}
});
ad.show();
```